# using <xsl:sort not functioning against assigned element

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

Hi I am pretty new to XSLT usage (without using xsl:for-each which might be the culprit) and am running into an issue trying to get sorting going for the party element to function as expected.

I have an XML document containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="president_table_PROBz.xsl"?>

        <presidents xmlnsxsi="http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsinoNamespaceSchemaLocation="http//www.du.edu/~mschwart/xml/president.xsd"
            date="2012-08-18">
            <president>
                <number>1</number>
                <name>George Washington</name>
                <birthday>2/22/1732</birthday>
                <took_office>1789-04-30</took_office>
                <left_office>1797-03-04</left_office>
                <party>no party</party>
                <term>
                    <number>1</number>
                    <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president>
                </term>
                <term>
                    <number>2</number>
                    <vice_president>John Adams</vice_president>
                </term>
            </president>

            <president>
                <number>2</number>
                <name>John Adams</name>
                <birthday>10/30/1735</birthday>
                <took_office>1797-03-04</took_office>
                <left_office>1801-03-04</left_office>
                <party>Federalist</party>
                <term>
                    <number>3</number>
                    <vice_president>Thomas Jefferson</vice_president>
                </term>
            </president>
            <president>
                <number>3</number>
                <name>Thomas Jefferson</name>
                <birthday>4/13/1743</birthday>
                <took_office>1801-03-04</took_office>
                <left_office>1809-03-04</left_office>
                <party>Democratic-Republican</party>
                <term>
                    <number>4</number>
                    <vice_president>Aaron Burr</vice_president>
                </term>
                <term>
                    <number>5</number>
                    <vice_president>George Clinton</vice_president>
                </term>
            </president>
            <president>
                <number>4</number>
                <name>James Madison</name>
                <birthday>3/16/1751</birthday>
                <took_office>1809-03-04</took_office>
                <left_office>1817-03-04</left_office>
                <party>Democratic-Republican</party>
                <term>
                    <number>6</number>
                    <vice_president>George Clinton</vice_president>
                </term>
                <term>
                    <number>7</number>
                    <vice_president>Elbridge Gerry</vice_president>
                </term>
            </president></presidents>
```

And an XSLT document where I am added items for other requests, but am now required to sort the data by party:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="president_table.css" />
            <title>Table of US Presidents</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Table of US Presidents</h1>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Birthday</th>
                <th>Took Office</th>
                <th>Left Ofice</th>
                <th>Party</th>
                <th>Vice President(s)</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="presidents">
                <xsl:sort select="party" order="descending"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="president">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="birthday"/></td>
        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="took_office"/></td>
        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="left_office"/></td>
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="party">
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:value-of select="party"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="term"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="term">
    <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. " />
    <xsl:value-of select="vice_president" /><br />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="party">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=". = 'Federalist'">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">Federalist</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=". = 'Democratic-Republican'">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">Democratic-Republican</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=". = 'Democratic'">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">Democratic</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=". = 'Republican'">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">Republican</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=". = 'Whig'">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">Whig</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">noparty</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I have searched around and nothing specific to what is happening exactly and I have followed instructions from a number of examples in attempt to get things sorted.

Thanks for any assistance in advance!!

Comment: `party` is a child of `president`, not `presidents`. Try changing your apply-templates to `select="presidents/president"`. (Untested since I'm on my phone.)

Comment: that was it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`party` is a child of `president`, not `presidents`. Try changing your apply-templates to `select="presidents/president"`.